# Swift array literal

Tags: swift

I'm creating a UICollisionBehavior like this:

```
let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: NSArray(object: self.squareView))
```

Why can't I say this instead:

```
let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.squareViews])
```

The compiler is happy with [""] but doesn't accept [self.sqareViews]
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple typo to me, I thin you mean `self.squareView`, not `self.squareView**s**`!

```
let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.squareView])
```

I have tested the following, and can confirm it compiles:

```
var view = UIView()
let collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [view])
```

Comment: No, but your comment with the code snippet did help! I forgot that Swift uses a slightly different model in instance variable initialisation as ObjC... With UIViewControllers for instance very often you'll want to have some instance vars which you only initialise in viewDidLoad etc. Now, in swift these are implemented by optionals. But you can't just refer to an optional by its name you have to unwrap it :) So this now works fine: UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.sqareView!]). I'm aftaid it wasnt the last time this caught me out :)))